# How to use parameter values from file instead parameters define in jenkin pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use a parameters values define in file instead the one define in parameters declarative. instead of YourName and environment define in pipeline script if i want to use the one define in parameters.txt file stored in /tmp/ directory. how we can use in jenkin pipeline script?
the reason to use this when running a nightly job we can define values to be use, since the extendedChoice parameters in declarative has a multiple values.

```
parameters {
string name: 'YourName', defaultValue: 'PQR', description: 'User Name'
}
environment {
MyENV="anyURL"
}
```

Comment: you can use another job to invoke this job with desired param value

Answer (score 1):

It's not immediately clear from your question what exactly are you trying to achieve, but there are two relevant options.

One is to use `parameterizedCron` plugin and to supply the parameters, if you know them at the time of your job definition, e.g. like this:

```
pipeline {
    triggers {
        parameterizedCron("H 1-5 * * * % MY_NAME=maratc; YOUR_NAME=veer1987")
    }
}
```

Assuming there are string parameters named `MY_NAME` and `YOUR_NAME`, they will receive the values provided.

The other one is for when you *don't* know the values at the job definition time and really only know them at the time of running the job. Assuming the values are written in `/${WORKSPACE}/nightly_params.txt` on the machine having `master` label:

```
YOUR_NAME = null
echo "This should be null: YOUR_NAME is ${YOUR_NAME}"

node('master') {
    stage("Define variable") {
        YOUR_NAME = readFile("${WORKSPACE}/nightly_params.txt").trim()
        echo "This is after reading the file: YOUR_NAME is ${YOUR_NAME}"
    }
}
    
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Use variable") {
            steps {
                echo "The YOUR_NAME variable is: ${YOUR_NAME}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```